# Comparing software version numbers using Text.PadStart to find the latest version number in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I was wondering if there was an easier way to write this code in PowerQuery where each of the [Installed.#] are columns that were created from a list in a previous step. The columns generated could increase or decrease. The same with the PadLength{#} is from a generated list in a previous step where the rows from the list could increase or decrease. The Installed.1 should always go with PadLength{0}, Installed.2 should always go with PadLength{1}, etc...

This code works but I have to go in and type each Installed.# and PadLength{#} if the number of rows in each list changes. I'm looking for a way it could automatically write this based off of the generated lists.

```
#"Duplicated Installed Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Expanded Supported Software", "Installed Version", "Installed"),
    #"Duplicated Image Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Installed Column", "Image Version", "Image"),
    #"Replaced Null Versions" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Duplicated Image Column",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Installed", "Image"}),
    InstalledSplitCount = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Null Versions", "InstalledSplitCount", each List.Count(Text.SplitAny([Installed], "."))),
    ImageSplitCount = Table.AddColumn(InstalledSplitCount, "ImageSplitCount", each List.Count(Text.SplitAny([Image], "."))),
    MaxSplitCount = Table.AddColumn(ImageSplitCount, "MaxSplitCount", each List.Max({[InstalledSplitCount],[ImageSplitCount]})),
    InstalledList = List.Transform({1..List.Max(MaxSplitCount[MaxSplitCount])}, each "Installed." & Text.From(_)),
    ImageList = List.Transform({1..List.Max(MaxSplitCount[MaxSplitCount])}, each "Image." & Text.From(_)),
    SplitInstalled = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Null Versions", "Installed", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.Csv), InstalledList),
    SplitImage = Table.SplitColumn(SplitInstalled, "Image", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.Csv), ImageList),
    ReplacedInstalledNull = Table.ReplaceValue(SplitImage,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue, InstalledList),
    ReplacedImageNull = Table.ReplaceValue(ReplacedInstalledNull,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue, ImageList),
    InstalledLength = List.Accumulate(InstalledList, ReplacedImageNull,(s,c)=>Table.TransformColumns(s,{c, each Text.Length(_), Int64.Type})),
    ImageLength = List.Accumulate(ImageList, InstalledLength,(s,c)=>Table.TransformColumns(s,{c, each Text.Length(_), Int64.Type})),
    UnpivotInstalled = Table.Unpivot(ImageLength, InstalledList, "Attribute", "Value"),
    GroupedInstalledLength = Table.Group(UnpivotInstalled, {"Attribute"}, {{"Max", each List.Max([Value]), type number}}),
    UnpivotImage = Table.Unpivot(ImageLength, ImageList, "Attribute", "Value"),
    GroupedImageLength = Table.Group(UnpivotImage, {"Attribute"}, {{"Max", each List.Max([Value]), type number}}),
    InstalledLength_Max = GroupedInstalledLength[Max],
    ImageLength_Max = GroupedImageLength[Max],
    MaxLengths = Table.FromRows(List.Zip({InstalledLength_Max, ImageLength_Max}), {"InstalledLength_Max", "ImageLength_Max"}),
    MaxLengthColumn = Table.AddColumn(MaxLengths, "MaxLength", each List.Max({[InstalledLength_Max],[ImageLength_Max]})),
    PadLength = MaxLengthColumn[MaxLength],
    Installed_Version = Table.AddColumn(ReplacedImageNull, "Installed_Version", each Text.PadStart([Installed.1], PadLength{0}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.2], PadLength{1}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.3], PadLength{2}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.4], PadLength{3}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.5], PadLength{4}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.6], PadLength{5}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.7], PadLength{6}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.8], PadLength{7}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.9], PadLength{8}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.10], PadLength{9}, "0") & "." & Text.PadStart([Installed.11], PadLength{10}, "0")),
```

Comment: You should be able to do this fairly simply with `List.Accumulate` or `List.Generate`. Without a data sample to work from, I would refer you to various blogs on how to use those functions.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried List.Accumulate and List.Generate but I haven't quite figured it out. I'm still new to Power Query and am teaching myself. Unfortunately, I can't share the data but I will work up a generic data set. I have a list of software versions where the version is listed out 123.12.1234 or 1.12.1234. and I need to get them all in the same format to be able to compare the version numbers to get the greatest version. I split the column based on the number of decimal points and create the Installed.# list based off of that. Then I am finding the Max Text.Length to Text.PadStart

Comment: Here is more of my code. I am doing the same with what we are providing on our image of computers to see if there is more recent versions installed then what is being installed on our image.

Answer (score 1):

Your code: TLDR
But your comment, that you want to convert dot separated numbers into a format to compare values can be done much more simply, I think.

For example (and this code will replicate a column containing the version numbers):

- Split the text string by the delimiter (dot)
- Find the maximum substring length to use as the Pad argument
- Transform the split text string by adding sufficient pad characters
- put it back together for comparison -- either textually or could use numeric in this instance.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords(
        {[Current Version = "123.12.1234"],
        [Current Version = "1.12.1234"]}
    ),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 
        let 
          parts = Text.Split([Current Version],"."),
          maxPadLength = List.Max(List.Transform(parts, each Text.Length(_))),
          padded = List.Transform(parts, each Text.PadStart(_,maxPadLength,"0"))
        in 
          Text.Combine(padded), type text)    
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: I just replicated your example and it works. It is much simpler than what I had in my code because I was breaking it apart and then mashing it back together and trying to find the Text.Length for each section of the Current Version.  How would you put the dots back in for the custom column? I have further down in my code, grouping each software version together and those that aren't at the latest version, I created a custom column to show that it can be upgraded to the latest version including the dots.

Comment: @Neiners Any delimiter can be specified as the second argument for the `Text.Combine(...)` function.  Check MS Help for that function.

Comment: thank you so much! This has worked and has saved me hours on refreshes from all of the different List.Max I was doing.